# NULLS LAST not working in ORDER BY with CASE

Tags: postgresql

I faced strange problem.

Here is a PostgreSQL function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION public.search_companies_ordered(name character varying DEFAULT NULL::character varying, "categoryIds" integer[] DEFAULT NULL::integer[], "cityIds" integer[] DEFAULT NULL::integer[], departments public.department[] DEFAULT NULL::public.department[], "stockTemperatures" public.stock_temperature[] DEFAULT NULL::public.stock_temperature[], "order" public.search_companies_order DEFAULT 'createdAt'::public.search_companies_order, order_type public.order_type DEFAULT 'desc'::public.order_type) RETURNS SETOF public.company
      LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE
      AS $$
        begin
          IF "search_companies_ordered"."order_type" = 'asc'::order_type THEN
            return query
            SELECT * FROM "search_companies"(
              name                := search_companies_ordered."name",
              "categoryIds"       := search_companies_ordered."categoryIds",
              "cityIds"           := search_companies_ordered."cityIds",
              departments         := search_companies_ordered.departments,
              "stockTemperatures" := search_companies_ordered."stockTemperatures"
            ) AS c
            ORDER BY (
              CASE WHEN "search_companies_ordered"."order" = 'id'::search_companies_order THEN
                c."id"
              END,
              CASE WHEN "search_companies_ordered"."order" = 'name'::search_companies_order THEN
                c."name"
              END,
              CASE WHEN "search_companies_ordered"."order" = 'createdAt'::search_companies_order THEN
                c."createdAt"
              END,
              CASE WHEN "search_companies_ordered"."order" = 'updatedAt'::search_companies_order THEN
                c."updatedAt"
              END,
              CASE WHEN "search_companies_ordered"."order" = 'lastCommentAt'::search_companies_order THEN
                c."lastCommentAt"
              END,
              CASE WHEN "search_companies_ordered"."order" = 'commentsCount'::search_companies_order THEN
                c."commentsCount"
              END
            ) ASC NULLS LAST;
          ELSE
            return query
            SELECT * FROM "search_companies"(
              name                := search_companies_ordered."name",
              "categoryIds"       := search_companies_ordered."categoryIds",
              "cityIds"           := search_companies_ordered."cityIds",
              departments         := search_companies_ordered.departments,
              "stockTemperatures" := search_companies_ordered."stockTemperatures"
            ) AS c
            ORDER BY (
              CASE WHEN "search_companies_ordered"."order" = 'id'::search_companies_order THEN
                c."id"
              END,
              CASE WHEN "search_companies_ordered"."order" = 'name'::search_companies_order THEN
                c."name"
              END,
              CASE WHEN "search_companies_ordered"."order" = 'createdAt'::search_companies_order THEN
                c."createdAt"
              END,
              CASE WHEN "search_companies_ordered"."order" = 'updatedAt'::search_companies_order THEN
                c."updatedAt"
              END,
              CASE WHEN "search_companies_ordered"."order" = 'lastCommentAt'::search_companies_order THEN
                c."lastCommentAt"
              END,
              CASE WHEN "search_companies_ordered"."order" = 'commentsCount'::search_companies_order THEN
                c."commentsCount"
              END
            ) DESC NULLS LAST;
          END IF;
          return;
        end;
        $$;
```

Everything working fine, except `NULLS LAST`, that does't takes any effect on resulting records order.

I've tried to omit brackets in `ORDER BY` – no effect:

```
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN "search_companies_ordered"."order" = 'id'::search_companies_order THEN
    c."id"
  END,
  CASE WHEN "search_companies_ordered"."order" = 'name'::search_companies_order THEN
    c."name"
  END,
  CASE WHEN "search_companies_ordered"."order" = 'createdAt'::search_companies_order THEN
    c."createdAt"
  END,
    CASE WHEN "search_companies_ordered"."order" = 'updatedAt'::search_companies_order THEN
    c."updatedAt"
  END,
  CASE WHEN "search_companies_ordered"."order" = 'lastCommentAt'::search_companies_order THEN
    c."lastCommentAt"
  END,
  CASE WHEN "search_companies_ordered"."order" = 'commentsCount'::search_companies_order THEN
    c."commentsCount"
  END
ASC NULLS LAST;
```

`search_companies` function is following:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION public.search_companies(name character varying DEFAULT NULL::character varying, "categoryIds" integer[] DEFAULT NULL::integer[], "cityIds" integer[] DEFAULT NULL::integer[], departments public.department[] DEFAULT NULL::public.department[], "stockTemperatures" public.stock_temperature[] DEFAULT NULL::public.stock_temperature[]) RETURNS SETOF public.company
    LANGUAGE sql STABLE
    AS $$
        SELECT DISTINCT ON (c."id")
          c.*
        FROM
          public.company AS c
        LEFT JOIN
          "companyCities" cC ON c.id = cC."companyId"
        LEFT JOIN
          "companyCategories" cCat ON c.id = cCat."companyId"
        LEFT JOIN
          "companyVisit" cv ON c.id = cv."companyId"
        WHERE (
          CASE WHEN "search_companies"."name" is not null THEN
            c.name ILIKE "search_companies"."name"
          ELSE true END
        ) AND (
          CASE WHEN "search_companies"."cityIds" is not null THEN
            "search_companies"."cityIds" @> array[cC."cityId"]
          ELSE true END
        ) AND (
          CASE WHEN "search_companies"."categoryIds" is not null THEN
            "search_companies"."categoryIds" @> array[cCat."categoryId"]
          ELSE true END
        ) AND (
          CASE WHEN "search_companies"."departments" is not null THEN
            "search_companies"."departments" @> array[cCat.department]
          ELSE true END
        ) AND (
          CASE WHEN "search_companies"."stockTemperatures" is not null THEN
            c."stockTemperatures" && "search_companies"."stockTemperatures"
          ELSE true END
        )
        ORDER BY c."id";
      $$;
```

Function `search_companies` is working.

```
select id, name, "lastCommentAt" from search_companies() order by "lastCommentAt" desc nulls last limit 100;
```

Where the problem is?

Answer (score 2):

`ASC`/`DESC` and `NULLS FIRST`/`NULLS LAST` do not affect all (comma separated) expressions in the `ORDER BY` clause, only the one where they stand.

So

```
... ORDER BY a, b, c DESC NULLS LAST
```

is the same as

```
... ORDER BY a ASC NULLS LAST,
             b ASC NULLS LAST,
             c DESC NULLS LAST
```

If you want all expressions sorted descending with the NULLs in the end, you'll have to append `DESC NULLS LAST` to each of the `ORDER BY` expressions.

Answer (score 1):

You're ENDing the CASEs early which creates multiple cases and that doesn't work well with `order by`.

Instead of:

```
ORDER BY (
          CASE WHEN "search_companies_ordered"."order" = 'id'::search_companies_order THEN
            c."id"
          END,
          CASE WHEN "search_companies_ordered"."order" = 'name'::search_companies_order THEN
            c."name"
          END,
          CASE WHEN "search_companies_ordered"."order" = 'createdAt'::search_companies_order THEN
            c."createdAt"
          END,
          CASE WHEN "search_companies_ordered"."order" = 'updatedAt'::search_companies_order THEN
            c."updatedAt"
          END,
          CASE WHEN "search_companies_ordered"."order" = 'lastCommentAt'::search_companies_order THEN
            c."lastCommentAt"
          END,
          CASE WHEN "search_companies_ordered"."order" = 'commentsCount'::search_companies_order THEN
            c."commentsCount"
          END
        ) ASC NULLS LAST;
```

Try:

```
ORDER BY 
          CASE WHEN "search_companies_ordered"."order" = 'id'::search_companies_order THEN
            c."id"
          WHEN "search_companies_ordered"."order" = 'name'::search_companies_order THEN
            c."name"
          WHEN "search_companies_ordered"."order" = 'createdAt'::search_companies_order THEN
            c."createdAt"
          WHEN "search_companies_ordered"."order" = 'updatedAt'::search_companies_order THEN
            c."updatedAt"
          WHEN "search_companies_ordered"."order" = 'lastCommentAt'::search_companies_order THEN
            c."lastCommentAt"
          WHEN "search_companies_ordered"."order" = 'commentsCount'::search_companies_order THEN
            c."commentsCount"
          END
          ASC NULLS LAST;
```

Comment: Not working, I'm getting – [1146] ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CASE"

Comment: Oh, no, It's migrating without errors. Testing the ordering…

Comment: Not working during execution, I'm getting error – ERROR: CASE types integer and character varying cannot be matched. I'ts because each CASE branch should return the same data type, but in my case, each column, that participates in ordering, has different type.

Comment: @AntonAL then add `::text` to _each one_ of the cases, e.g. `CASE WHEN "search_companies_ordered"."order" = 'id'::search_companies_order THEN
            c."id"::text`